# Loadng pictures in threads: Duplicates

Tags: java, multithreading, image, concurrency, duplicates

Thread problem. Im trying to load images from a set of urls by threadpoolexecutor. I keep track on the urls that have been tried in a hashset and only execute a task if the url hasn't been used before. I add the loaded pictures and its decently fast, but I get duplicates because the threads keep adding. The added objects have to be decleared as new instances because Im using the SettingPicture data object to store images. This is causing duplicates. Code here : http://pastebin.com/Hyatpsbu

Comment: why you need this while loop and triedPic set, isnt for loop enough?

btw. HashSet operates on hashcodes so if you want to not have duplicates in your hashset you have to ovvrride it

Comment: That while loop is a terrible idea. Have you counted how many tasks you enqueue there? Should be like 100 immediately because submitting tasks is instant and nothing changes the condition of your while loop. Your code is furthermore absolutely not thread-safe (that's where the duplicates come from). And since your method there blocks until all images are loaded (or not) anyways, have you considered to use no threads at all?

Comment: I tried using just the foor loop, but then I got very variable result. The PictureData list (which I get the urls from) have 100 urls, but I usually ended up with 20-50 pictures and I need to make sure I get all. Not using threads was too slow - like 30 seconds on startup so its not an option.

Comment: Blocking out while give me NO pictures :S